# Unable to install an updated App from play store

Tags: android, google-play

I am finding problem in downloading App from play store. I had earlier installed the App, then uninstalled it.

Now there is an update available to the App and I want to download it again.
Google play gives me an error message Attached Screenshot.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Are you downloading this in Lollipop version ?

Comment: Actually I have multiple accounts synced to the Google play. but now i am not able to download it using any of it.

Comment: I knew it already :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens in Lollipop version since it allows multiple users on a single device. To remove a particular application for all the users please follow these steps,

- Go to Settings,
- Select "Apps"
- Swipe left and chose "All" tab
- Scroll down to bottom (This will show you some "Not installed" apps )
- [image]
- Open that application
- Click on right top icon and choose "Uninstall for all user"
  [image]
- Done

Comment: Thanks, it worked !!! i had to uninstall the App for all user from overflow button at the top right.